# Apache 2.4 virtual host on different port than 80

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4

When reading the articles it all seems easy, but I am unable to get this to work. I run apache 2.4.7 Several virtual hosts are running just fine. I need one virtual host to run at port 8080 only. So I added Listen 8080 to ports.conf

In the virtualhost conf file:

> VirtualHost *:8080

After a restart I am not getting the virtual host. I do see the default server page and I also notice that the Listen 8080 line is working.

What am I forgetting?

Comment: View `netstat -lt` command results, is the port 8080 listening? Check firewall settings.

Comment: Yep, port is listening.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely forgot to add line:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

Comment: This is for Apache2.2, I am using Apache 2.4

Comment: You are actually absolutely correct, in apache 2.4 NameVirtualHost is deprecated.